How to programmatically check if a Jenkins multi-branch pipeline scan has completed?
I use the Build pipeline plugin when triggering a job from a pipeline script, like this, where I set the wait condition to true since I want the job to finish before continuing.
build job: "some-multi-branch-pipeline/master",
      parameters: [ 
        string(name: "BUILD_NODE", value: buildNode),
        booleanParam(name: "RUN_TESTS", value: env.RUN_TESTS.toBoolean()),
        booleanParam(name: "RUN_SONAR", value: env.RUN_SONAR.toBoolean()),
        booleanParam(name: "CONFIRM", value: confirm)
      ],
      propagate: true,
      wait: true

However, wait doesn't apply when triggering a scan on a multi-branch pipeline, which is done by simply triggering a build on the pipeline itself, like this
build job: "some-multi-branch-pipeline",
      wait: true

I get the error
ERROR: Waiting for non-job items is not supported

So I resort to putting a sleep(120) function after the scan to wait for 2 minutes for example. However I think it's kludgy. Is there a way to programmatically check if the pipeline scan has finished?

This is not very straight forward, but yes, you can check programmatically if a pipeline scan has finished without resorting to a fixed sleep period, which can be unreliable and inefficient.
Proposed solution

Trigger the multi-branch pipeline scan: Use the build step to trigger the scan.
Poll for completion: Use a loop to periodically check the build status of the triggered job using the Jenkins REST API.
Proceed once the scan is complete: Continue with your pipeline once the scan is complete.

Groovy script
// Trigger the multi-branch pipeline scan
build job: "some-multi-branch-pipeline", wait: false

// Polling function to check the status of the scan
def isScanFinished(jobName, buildNumber) {
    def response = httpRequest(
        url: "${JENKINS_URL}/job/${jobName}/${buildNumber}/api/json",
        authentication: 'your-jenkins-credentials',
        validResponseCodes: '200,404'
    )

    if (response.status == 404) {
        return false // The job hasn't started yet
    }

    def jsonResponse = new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(response.content)
    return jsonResponse.result != null
}

// Poll until the scan job is finished
def scanJobName = "some-multi-branch-pipeline" # You can customize it depending on your parameters
def scanBuildNumber = "XXX" # Using Jenkins API

timeout(time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES') {
    waitUntil {
        script {
            isScanFinished(scanJobName, scanBuildNumber)
        }
    }
}

// Continue with the rest of your pipeline
echo "Scan job completed. Proceeding with the pipeline..."


EDIT
If you want to avoid the following error and trigger the scan ONLY
ERROR: Waiting for non-job items is not supported

You can use this script that works on the Jenkins 2.466.
Know that you will need to approve both functions getItemByFullName and scheduleBuild2.
// Define the name of your multi-branch pipeline job
def jobName = "XXXXXXXXX"
// Get the multi-branch pipeline job
def multibranchJob = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName)

// Check if the job exists
if (multibranchJob) {
    // Trigger the scan
    multibranchJob.scheduleBuild2(0)
    println "Triggered scan for multi-branch pipeline job: ${jobName}"
} else {
    println "Job not found: ${jobName}"
}


Nice, I'll test it next week and will provide feedback.

I get java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getProjectName() on null object

and indeed if I do echo "${scanJob.getClass()}" I get class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject

@ChrisF are you sure build command triggered the job ?

yes, I was watching it.

@ChrisF I used this in ol' days so I guess my Jenkins version is just outdated.
Yet, you can still set scanJobName (and cust with special branch names ... depending on the parameters of the build command) and the scanBuildNumber  can be set easily using the jenkins API.
Clearly, this solution is not straight-forward at all and probably not the best way to do it.

@ChrisF can you check my edit ? this should work

The code in the EDIT section worked, but it seems like it just does the same thing as the build step with the wait: false option. I don't get how to use it with your original code.
